# How do I implement an IConfigurationProvider depending on another IConfigurationProvider without specific ordering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently investigating how to deal with the following setup.

I have an official source, which will provide the location of a custom configuration file, which I need to load from another provider.

Here is an exemplary approach:

```
void Main()
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "FilePath", "foobar"} })
        .AddCustomSource();
        
    configBuilder.Build();
}

public static class IConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddCustomSource(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var temporaryConfig = builder.Build();
        return builder.Add(new ConfigSource(temporaryConfig));
    }
}

public class ConfigSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    public ConfigSource(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new ConfigProvider(_configuration);
    }
}

public class ConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    public ConfigProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Loading from file: {configuration["FilePath"]}");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the big catch here is that the order is very important. If I would add the inmemory collection after adding the custom source, then this would fall apart, since the temporary builder does not provider the respective configuration anymore at that point in time.

I am wondering how I could solve this and lift the order restriction off the whole sytem.

Is there an official approach to this? My ideas so far basically circulated around having an event which I would pass to custom sources, to which they can register in order to receive the "complete" `IConfiguration` after building it. However, this feels off:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static event Action<IConfiguration> OnConfigBuilt;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCustomSource(onBuiltCb =>
            {
                OnConfigBuilt += builtConfig => onBuiltCb(builtConfig);
            })
            .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "FilePath", "foobar" } });

        var config = configBuilder.Build();
        OnConfigBuilt?.Invoke(config);
    }
}

public static class IConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddCustomSource(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, Action<Action<IConfiguration>> onBuiltCb)
    {
        var temporaryConfig = builder.Build();
        return builder.Add(new ConfigSource(temporaryConfig, handler => onBuiltCb(handler)));
    }
}

public class ConfigSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    private Action<Action<IConfiguration>> _onBuiltCb;
    
    public ConfigSource(IConfiguration configuration, Action<Action<IConfiguration>> onBuiltCb)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _onBuiltCb = onBuiltCb;
    }
    
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new ConfigProvider(_configuration, _onBuiltCb);
    }
}

public class ConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    public ConfigProvider(IConfiguration configuration, Action<Action<IConfiguration>> onBuiltCb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Loading from file: {configuration["FilePath"]}");
        onBuiltCb(newConfig => Console.WriteLine($"Got new config: {newConfig["FilePath"]}"));
    }
}

// Loading from file: 
// Got new config: foobar
```

This way, I could at least trigger a reload of the configuration from within, and eventually have it bubble up. But it still relies on explicit work, by calling the event.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Fail early.  Have the provider check for the missing configuration and throw an exception if it is missing at the point in time when it is needed.

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you tryin to recreate existing functionality? What differentiates the custom source that prevents it from being used by the built-in providers?

Comment: Hey @Nkosi, thanks for the link. I think it might look like a XY problem since the example I made is very simplified, but the configuration setup I'm looking for is in fact not a default scenario